# Force img Element to Fill Container Height and Width

Tags: css, image, overflow, crop

I've got this gallery I'm currently building, and I'm trying to work out how to get my images to fill their containers.

I don't mind if they're cropped a little, I just would like them to fill the the full height and width of their parent element `.thumb`.

My HMTL looks like this:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
   <li class="thumb">
   <a href="#"><img src="/img.jpg"></a>
   </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

And my CSS like this:

```
.thumbs .thumb {
  background: red;
  height: 33.5294118%;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I've got a demo set up over here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/hjvBG

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .thumb a to your .thumb img definition (so the a element is 100% width as well) - you may also have to make one or both (a/img) tags display: block and height 100% as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a class to the img element, like:

`<img src="/img.jpg" class="img-class">`

and the css.

> .img-class{    width:100%;    height: 100%; }